# Why does the Sun tlddoc tag documentation generator fail under powershell?

Tags: java, powershell

When building documentation for JSP tags under Powershell, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.tlddoc.tagfileparser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at     line 21, column 114.  Encountere
d: "\u0153" (339), after : ""
        at     com.sun.tlddoc.tagfileparser.TagFileTokenManager.getNextToken(TagFileTokenManager.java:1693)
    at com.sun.tlddoc.tagfileparser.TagFile.jj_consume_token(TagFile.java:494)
    at com.sun.tlddoc.tagfileparser.TagFile.JSPDirective(TagFile.java:172)
    at com.sun.tlddoc.tagfileparser.TagFile.JSPTagDef(TagFile.java:90)
    at com.sun.tlddoc.tagfileparser.TagFile.Input(TagFile.java:43)
    at com.sun.tlddoc.tagfileparser.TagFile.parse(TagFile.java:20)
```

The same code runs just fine when run under Eclipse. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm noting this issue here for future reference.

Under Powershell, the default charset is windows-1252. Under Eclipse (and probably cmd.exe) it is ISO-8859-1.

Adding the line `System.setProperty("file.encoding", "ISO-8859-1");` to my application allowed the application to run in Powershell and Eclipse just fine.